# index masked element Array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a array

```
z = np.random.random((10,10))  --> two dimensions
```

with a mask

```
y,x=np.mgrid[slice(0,61, 1),slice(0,106, 1)] 

sorted = np.sort(z,axis=None)
mask = ma.masked_inside(z,sorted[10],sorted[-10])
```

mask is Array masked inside only the 10 min element and 10 max inside with a mask TRUE. I need the index position to put x,y in the annotate, but only like create element that is masked

I will like return mask elements masked and the **index position in the axis** of all the elements to create a automatic annotates objects

```
 ax.annotate(str(j)+" Altura",xy=(i,j))
```

Answer (score 3):

To return the "index position", use `np.where` on the mask. For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2,7,9],[9,1,4],[8,7,2]])
idx = A<3 # The mask

print np.where(idx)
print zip(*np.where(idx))
```

Gives:

```
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

that is, the locations where `A<3`. I find zipping over the elements and packaging them as a list of tuples useful, but use the first representation to index them back from the original array.

Comment: Thank you. And if I have the array masked in this moment. this is my final array masked _f_data= np.ma.masked_array(np.around(z, decimals=4, out=None),~_c)

Comment: @virtualsets I'm not sure I understand what you're asking in that comment.

Comment: I not understand your mask, my mask is ~c and is the joint of two another mask. I have one mask ~c and one array z